# download button disappear after editing data table in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shinyjs

I have included editable table in my shiny app I developed in my organization. Use this simple example to illustrate the issue. This is an extension of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188784/download-button-disappear-when-deselecting-column-or-editing-data-table-in-shiny/58193227#58193227)

In this app, after I edit any cell,  the download button just disappear.  Does anyone know why that happens? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

# UI
ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("nrows",
                "select n entries",
                choices = 100:150,
                selected = 100,
                multiple = FALSE),
    downloadButton("download1", "Download iris as csv"),
    DTOutput('tbl'),
    checkboxGroupInput(
        'datacols', 
        label='Select Columns:',
        choices= c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Species'),
        selected = c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Species'),
        inline=TRUE)

)

# SERVER
server = function(input, output) {

    dat = reactiveValues()
    observe ({

        dat$dat = iris[1:input$nrows, ]

    })
    # render DT
    output$tbl = renderDT({
        datatable(dat$dat,
                  editable = "cell",
                  callback = JS(
                      "$('div.dwnld').append($('#download1'));",
                      "var checkboxes = $('input[name=datacols]');",
                      "checkboxes.each(function(index,value){",
                      "  var column = table.column(index+1);",
                      "  $(this).on('click', function(){",
                      "    if($(this).prop('checked')){",
                      "      column.visible(true);",
                      "    }else{",
                      "      column.visible(false);",
                      "    }",
                      "  });",
                      "});"
                  ),
                  extensions = "Buttons",
                  options = list(
                      dom = 'B<"dwnld">frtip',
                      buttons = list("copy")
                  ) 
        )

    })

    observeEvent(input[["tbl_cell_edit"]], {
        cellinfo <- input[["tbl_cell_edit"]]
        dat$dat <<- editData(dat$dat, cellinfo, "tbl")
    })

    output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste("data_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(dat$dat %>% select(one_of(input$datacols)), file)
        }
    )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You can get rid of the issue by setting ```server = FALSE``` in DT::renderDT, and add "csv" as one of the buttons in Bfrtip datatables. But setting ```server = FALSE``` sends the entire table to the browser at one, which is not good if your table is very large.

Comment: @raymkchow     `sever=FALSE` is the other solution. But I ran into another issue with this.  I have a question related to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194938/edited-cell-in-data-table-goes-back-to-its-original-value-after-check-uncheck-co